# Flutter changing screens with linked text

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with changing screens on linked text, so at first I only needed to change between two screens, Login and Register page, I then needed to add a third screen "OwnerRegisterPage" to the mix.

[Main Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVnzd.png)

This is my login page, as you can see I have a place for Register and Owner register.

I also have an auth page as an inbetween for changing screens, this is the new code I added as an attempt to change between three screens but it is not working.

[Auth.dart code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ29H.png)

Do you guys have any recommendation on how I could do this by using the same method ?

Comment: Could you please share the code of login screen too?

Comment: Hey Rashid, I have added my login screen code under

Answer (score 0):

```
I should have added in my code for my login screen.

// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

import 'forgot_password.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback showRegisterPage;
  final VoidCallback showOwnerRegisterPage;
  const LoginPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.showRegisterPage,
    required this.showOwnerRegisterPage,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  // text controller

  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future signIn() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text.trim(),
      password: _passwordController.text.trim(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 198, 220, 228),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child:
                Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.local_parking,
                size: 100,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),

              // Hello text
              Text(
                'Hello Again!',
                style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                  fontSize: 45,
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),

              Text(
                'Welcome back to ParkALot',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 17,
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),

              //email

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _emailController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Email',
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                    filled: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),

              //password
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                child: TextField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Password',
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                    filled: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return forgotPasswordPage();
                        }));
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Forgot Password?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),

              //signin Button
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: signIn,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Sign In',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),

              //Parker Registry Button
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Not a member?',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: widget.showRegisterPage,
                    child: Text(
                      ' Register now',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),

              //Owner Registry Button
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Want to be an Owner?',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: widget.showOwnerRegisterPage,
                    child: Text(
                      ' Register now',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```